# Neo4j Cypher get nodes until reaching relationship with given properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an Neo4j Cypher query I struggling with. What I want is to have all nodes with a given relationship, until it reach a relation with an properties who is below a given number ( < 25). All nodes after that relationship is found should be skipped.

Here a sample of my graph:

[image: Sample graph]

and how I would like the result to be (every nodes after relationship IS_OWNER with Share < 25 should be skipped)

[image: The desired result]

I hope someone can show how to write the Cypher query who can give the desired result (picture 2) from the sample graph (picture 1). Every nodes after relationship IS_OWNER with Share < 25 should be skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ALL() function should work here, letting you specify that all relationships in the path should have Share >= 25, and pruning further expansion otherwise.

Something like this, assuming starting at company C:

```
MATCH (:Company{name:'C'})-[rels:IS_OWNER*0..]-(companies)
WHERE all(rel in rels WHERE rel.Share >= 25)
RETURN companies
```

EDIT:

While it seems like using a variable on the variable-length relationship is deprecated in the newer versions of neo4j (I'll double-check on that, doesn't seem like a good decision), here's another way to specify this which gets around the warning:

```
MATCH p = (:Company{name:'C'})-[:IS_OWNER*0..]-(companies)
WHERE all(rel in relationships(p) WHERE rel.Share >= 25)
RETURN companies
```

Comment: It seams to work but I got an warning, so I would be pleased to have an solution where this solution also will work with newer versions of Ne4j. Do you know how to solve this warning?

"This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated. (org.neo4j.graphdb.impl.notification.NotificationDetail$Factory$2@1c973114)"

It seams that it is the use of alias in front of multiple relation who cause this, because if I remove rels or remove *0.. from  -[rels:IS_OWNER*0..]- it disapear

Comment: Good point, I added an alternate query which should get around the warning.